# Why does my plot show random intercepts if I use the fitted values of a random intercept model?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, mixed-models

I'm using intensive-longitudinal data to calculate a random intercept model with the following code:

```
model1a <- lmerTest::lmer(MET_mean_log ~ Stress_RQ1 + Time + (1 | id), data = data_mini_clean)
```

In a next step I'm extracting the fitted values with this code:

```
data_mini_clean$MET_fittedvalues_model1a <- fitted(model1a)
```

Now I'm using the ggplot()-function to create a spaghetti plot using Stress_RQ1 as my independent variable and MET_fittedvalues_model1a as my dependent variable:

```
ggplot(data_mini_clean, aes(x = Stress_RQ1, y = MET_fittedvalues_model1a, group = factor(id), color = factor(id))) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE) +
  scale_color_viridis_d(option = "F", alpha = 0.3, begin = 0, end = 1) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = lm, se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE, color = "blue") +
  labs(x = "Stress_RQ1", y = "MET_mean (log, fitted)") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

This creates [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhaj3.png)

I don't understand, why this plot shows regression lines that have different slopes. Since I used the random intercept model, all regression lines should have the same beta-coefficients, which I've double checked with the code

```
beta_coefficients <- coef(model1a)$id[, "Stress_RQ1"]
```

How can I correct the code so that all regression lines have the same slope?

I have tried adding the formula `y ~ x + 0.01612179` to the `geom_smooth()`-function in order to force R to only use this beta-coefficient, but that only produces an error code.

Comment: This is because you are grouping by `factor(id)`. Try only `color = factor(id)`, it's probably enough to produce the same plot.

Comment: Maybe if you’re plotting fitted values, just use geom_line.

Comment: @RuiBarradas when I run the code without "group = factor(id)", the plot looks the same.

Comment: @tjebo I tried this code: `ggplot(data=data_mini_clean_no575978, aes(x=Stress_RQ1, y=MET_fittedvalues_model1a_no575978, group=factor(id))) +
  geom_line()` but this only made a plot that connects all the data points of each subject. I would like a regression line for each subject.

Comment: @Laura That's what I meant by the second part of my comment, `color = factor(id)` will group the data by `id`. Why do you need different colors, one per `id`?  Isn't, for instance, `alpha = 0.5` put outside `aes()` enough? Try `ggplot(data_mini_clean, aes(x = Stress_RQ1, y = MET_fittedvalues_model1a))+geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE, alpha = 0.5) + etc`

Comment: @RuiBarradas I might have misunderstood you. I used this code you suggested: `ggplot(data_mini_clean, aes(x = Stress_RQ1, y = MET_fittedvalues_model1a)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE, alpha = 0.5)` Unfortunately, this creates a plot with only one line. How could I add regression lines for each participant if no id is mentioned?

Comment: @Laura If you add regression lines per id, then they should have different slopes, no? If you want them all to have the same color, use `group = factor(id)`. But each triplet `(id, Stress_RQ1, MET_fittedvalues_model1a)` will have its regression line.

Comment: @Rui Barradas No actually that's what I'm hung up on. Since the MET_fittedvalues_model1a are the fitted values of a model that assumes no random slope, every id should have the same slope. Or did I not understand this correctly? That's why I also showed the code for the extraction of the beta-values of this model (`beta_coefficients <- coef(model1a)$id[, "Stress_RQ1"]`) which showed me that all ids have the same beta-coefficient, which should equal the same incline for each regression line.